# jQuery hover appendto not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I have a jquery image scroller which when reaches the last `<li>` appends the first `<li>` and so on. But when i am using hover instead of onclick it not working below is the code

```
  jQuery("#gallery-next").click(function () {
     next_scroll();
 });

 function next_scroll() {
     if (jQuery("#gallery").position().left > stopPosition && !jQuery("#gallery").is(":animated")) {
         jQuery("#gallery").animate({
             left: "-=" + imageWidth + "px"
         });
     }
     if (jQuery("#gallery").position().left == stopPosition) {
         $("#gallery > li:first").appendTo("#gallery").fadeIn('slow');
         return false;
     }
 }
```

What should I do to make the mouseenter/hover work instead of click function. I have seen other solutions on this forum which is quite similar, but I am not able to utilize those. So please answer with a code. That will be much helpful. 
Here is a link to check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rogerblake/e4npa/1/)
Thanks in advance

Comment: whether is it displays any error using mouseenter

Comment: Perhaps you can add your html code or make a jsfiddle. **note:** this is not a forum is a QA site

Comment: No its not displaying any error. It just appends once. Then again if I move the mouse out and again reenter the mouse the effect(append) takes place. But I want a continuous process.

Comment: @Tom Sarduy : Yes. I know. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: Oh, that's a different question, if the user remains over the `#gallery-next` you want to call `next_scroll()` every x seconds right?

Comment: @Tom Sarduy : yes. Thats what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, what you need is to change this:

```
jQuery("#gallery-next").click(function () {
    next_scroll();
});
```

for this one:

```
var timer = 0;
jQuery("#gallery-next").
mouseover(function () {
     //Call next_scroll() every two seconds
     timer = setInterval(next_scroll, 2000);})
.mouseout(function(){
     timer = clearInterval(timer);
});
```

**Update:** Is `setInterval()` not `setTimeOut()`, sorry about the confusion, check [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4npa/3/)

Comment: Yes Thats more about it. The scroll is working but when it reaches the end the appendto is not working properly.

Comment: try change `$("#gallery > li:first")` for this: `jQuery("#gallery > li:first")`

Comment: Nope. Not working. Same problem. The `appendto` is creating problem. If I move out the mouse and again reenter its appending twice or thrice.

Comment: I gave only one "Previous" link for you to test.

Comment: The problem was that you was executing the two if at the same time, use `else if`, so it will do append and animate, and that why you was getting that effect. check [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e4npa/2/)

Comment: The updated fiddle is not working continuously. i want to scroll continuously when mouseover. Thats not happening

Comment: I have checked. But its working only the first time I make the mouseover. Not going continuous. The cycling effect is not happening

Comment: Are you sure, this is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/e4npa/3/ and it's working for me o.O

Comment: Its working now. Thanks a lot man. If you edit the answer I will upvote it and accept it. Thanks a lot again

Comment: Bro, disturbing you again. I tried to implement the code you provided to my "Next" button. Its working, but when I move out my mouse it still scrolls. It doesnot stop. But for the "Prev" button it works perfectly. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestion?

Comment: be sure that you are doing `clearInterval(timer);` or share your code on jsFiddle ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23209/discussion-between-tom-sarduy-and-roger)